# Use batch response file to send Enter (blank line)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a program which runs in a Windows command window and requires user interaction.

I'd like to call the program programatically, with responses located in a batch response file.

I can successfully give my program responses using the command

```
Program.exe < responses.txt
```

One of the questions simply requires the user to press 'enter'. How do I send that in the response file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can just leave a blank line as per line 3 in the image below. This results in the 'enter' key stroke being sent.

[image]